# Cannot interact with rgl plots on Debian linux

Tags: linux, r, rgl

The 3D plot using [rgl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) cannot interact with mouse on my linux (specifically Debian 8 Jessie with RGL 0.95.1247). Just a RGL device window with fixed size is shown. I cannot even google out realted problems. Is it from my setting flaws?

code and figure:

```
$ demo(rgl)
```

[image]

Comment: It works for me. But this is not a programming problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter so much which rgl version you have -- but it matters wheter you have OpenGL support in your graphics driver.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel , how to test the OpenGL support? Or even the plotting of RGL figure does not confirm my OpenGL configuration? PS. I have a graphic card GT 640 and Nvidia driver installed.

Comment: `glxinfo` from package mesa-utils should help.

Comment: @Pascal ... a classic programmatic response. But I need to explore the data in an interactive way before exporting it in a programming way. Have you made any specific configuration on your system?

Comment: Yes, I installed required libraries, as described here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html (section "SystemRequirements").

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel It seems that OpenGL is driven properly by Nvidia driver. Still not solved.

Comment: Search for something like `mesa-common-dev`, `libglu1-mesa-dev` et `libgl1-mesa-dev`.

Comment: @Pascal They are all installed. I think its not a dependence problem. Otherwise, the `library(rgl)` cannot be loaded and the program can not be run.

Comment: If you run the Linux command `glxinfo` (as indicated by @DirkEddelbuettel), what do you get? Particularly the direct rendering (`glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"`). On my computer, it is "yes".

Comment: @Pascal It was Yes, too, for me. PS: I can plot rgl figures both statically and in animation, but still not drag the plot with my mouse. Linux curse?